# IMAP Account Migration/Synchronisation

Tags: migration, synchronization, imap

I was wondering if anyone knew of any easy way to synchronise and then migrate an IMAP account between two hosting accounts? I have SSH access but within jailshell (cpanel/WHM access also), but no root access to the server. Host may be willing to provide assistance if I can give them a little more information on what I am actually requesting.

*Read below for background information*

I previously had my own personal use hosting account, which I ended up putting a few friends businesses on the back of as Addon-domains, which gradually grew to more than was practical. I have since bought some reseller space on a server and have created their own accounts so they can self manage a majority of their issues.

Since then I have steadily merged everyone over, as they were all using POP3 for their e-mail accounts. Although a good friend of mine has an IMAP account with a considerable number of e-mails in various folders. She also relies on access to her e-mail as she runs her own business, so downtime would preferably be kept to a minimum.

As mentioned above I was wondering of anyone knows how I could go about syncing her account with the new host primarily. I can just update her name servers to propagate the domain over afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've performed massive migrations using [imapsync](http://freshmeat.net/projects/imapsync/). For small batches [imapcopy](http://code.google.com/p/imapcopy/) looks like a viable alternative.

Comment: +1 for imapsync I have used it for migrating several hundred thousands of accounts between systems.